# How to make the label title and input value the same, but id is different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I have question, how i can make the label title and input value the same, but id is different. Code below show what i want.

```
<%= f.input :building_type, :label_html => {:class => "ui-priority n1"}, 
    label: "Building type", collection: Post::Flat::BUILDING_TYPES, as: :radio %>


Post::Flat::BUILDING_TYPES = [["Flat-super", 1], ["Flat-middle", 2]]
```

Output code:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label class="choice" for="post_flat_building_type-1">
    <input id="post_flat_building_type-1" name="post_flat[building_type]" type="radio" value="1">
    Flat-super
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="choice" for="post_flat_building_type-2">
    <input id="post_flat_building_type-2" name="post_flat[building_type]" type="radio" value="2">
    Flat-middle
  </label>
</div>
```

But i want to make value equals to **Flat-super, Flat-middle**, how i can achieve this ?

Thank you for any help!

Formtastic version - 2.3
Formtastic-bootstrap version - 3.0

----- Some addition----

Someone tells that i can solve this problem by change initial array to

```
Post::Flat::BUILDING_TYPES = [["Flat-super", "Flat-super"], ["Flat-middle", "Flat-middle"]]
```

But it not work if i have cyrillic

```
Post::Flat::BUILDING_TYPES = [["Кирпичный", "Кирпичный"]

<div class="radio">
  <label class="choice" for="post_flat_building_type">
   <input id="post_flat_building_type" name="post_flat[building_type]" type="radio" value="кирпичный">
    кирпичный
  </label>
</div>
```

You can observe that output contain wrong id, it affects if i have more than 1 object in my array. All inputs will have the same id.

Comment: did you try: `Post::Flat::BUILDING_TYPES = [["Flat-super", "Flat-super"], ["Flat-middle", "Flat-middle"]]` instead?

Comment: This will not work if i try to work with cyrillic words.

Comment: For example - Post::Flat::BUILDING_TYPES = [["Кирпичный", "Кирпичный"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If problem occurs only when creating checkboxes and radiobuttons, try to hack formtastic, transliting characters from cyrrilic to latin when creating attribute `id` of `input` and attribute `for` of `label`.

```
module Formtastic
  module Inputs
    module Base
      module Choices

        def choice_html_safe_value(choice)
          name = Translit.convert(choice_value(choice).to_s, :english)
          name.gsub(/\s/, '_').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase
        end

      end # Choices
    end
  end
end
```

You can use gem `translit` or make translit by yourselves. After hacking, formtastic will generate something like this:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label class="choice" for="post_flat_building_type_kirpichnyj">
    <input id="post_flat_building_type_kirpichnyj" name="post_flat[building_type]" type="radio" value="кирпичный">
    кирпичный
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need "beautiful" html and id\for naming, you can use `.hash` method to make it unique.

Here is the example I'm using (no need to Translit anything)

```
module Formtastic
  module Inputs
    module Base
      module Choices

        def choice_html_safe_value(choice)
          choice_value(choice).hash
        end

      end # Choices
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple array, not array of arrays

```
[ "Flat-super", "Flat-super" ]
```